# Should I flag questions to replace faded out close reasons into currently available close reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015932) question is closed as too localized currently, but I think it is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874802), which duplicate is a currently available close reason. Is it worth to flag a question to replace the faded out close reason into a currently available reason if I found the current one is applicable (and more suitable)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have only a limited number of close votes per day and not enough users that spend them daily I really wouldn't bother to re-open and then re-close a question, only to fix the close reason. We have more pressing issues to focus on, mainly the fresh posts that come in daily.

You could leave a comment though:

> Possible duplicate: link to other question

That will help future visitors find the duplicate.